# How can I repair a broken window shade string?

Tags: windows

The string on my pleated shade has broken and I'm having tough time in putting it back into its pulley. What’s the best way to fix it? The photos show one that is fine and working and the one that is broken and needs to be fixed.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Working Window Blind String]

[image: Broken Window Blind Top]

[image: Broken Window Blind Bottom]

[image: Broken Window Blind Bottom]

Comment: Maybe step back and get one pic that gives an overall view. Looking at the pics in the edit history, it was hard to interpret what was going on, especially since they were rotated somewhat randomly. If you'll repost them, someone will be kind enough to rotate them so up is up.

Comment: @jsotola - I have uploaded the images again, please take a look and let me know if it looks fine. Thanks

Comment: Looks good now. I imagine that you'll need to dismount the blind from its clips and then figure out how to remove the plastic end cap. The clips often release with a little upward pressure on the front. Do you have a brand name?

Comment: @jsotola I am asking about the broken string, how can I put it back into those clips. Does it makes sense?

Comment: @isherwood - looks like the brand name is Graber.

Comment: I am not sure what you call that white object in the last picture and got this idea from Isherwood’s post. If you see the first picture, the string is supposed to go through it.

Comment: the white thing appears to be a fob of some kind ... it does not appear to be related to the question, since it is not the focus of any of the pictures ... if it is important, then it should fill 90% of the image

Comment: I'd say take the whole assembly off the window frame and examine the end with the broken string closely

Comment: I will try that.